# ScannerError in brownie-config.yaml

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, yaml

I am following this guide: https://youtu.be/p36tXHX1JD8 (26:23)
I typed everything in the brownie-cinfig.yaml like in the video

```
dependencies: 
— OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin—contracts@3.4.0
— smartcontractkit/chainlink—brownie—contracts@1.0.2
compiler: 
solc: 
remappings: 
 — '@openzeppelin=OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin—contracts@3.4.0' 
 — '@chainlink=smartcontractkit/chainlink—brownie—contracts@1.0.2'
```

But I get this error:

```
 File "yaml/scanner.py", line 291, in stale_possible_simple_keys
raise ScannerError("while scanning a simple key", key.mark,
ScannerError: while scanning a simple key
  in "/mnt/c/Users/Public/nft-from-scratch/brownie-config.yaml", line 3, column 1
could not find expected ':'
  in "/mnt/c/Users/Public/nft-from-scratch/brownie-config.yaml", line 4, column 1
```

What could be wrong? I understand the code is missing ':', but on the video there are no extra ':' and code works fine. I tried adding ':' to the ends of line 3/4, but I still get error. It's just that that error is now: `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable`
So I don't think these lines should end with ':'

Answer (score 1):

You need to use an ASCII [Hyphen-minus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyphen-minus) (`-`) instead of a Unicode [em dash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dash#Em_dash) (`—`). While they look quite similar, YAML understands only the former one as special character in its syntax.