# brownie compile --- AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'

Tags: compilation, get, attributeerror

im trying to compile brownie code:

```
dependencies:
 - smartcontractkit/chainlink-brownie-contracts@0.2.1
 - OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts@4.3.0
compiler:
  solc:
    version: 0.8.7
    remappings:
     - '@chainlink=smartcontractkit/chainlink-brownie-contracts@0.2.1'
     - '@openzeppelin=OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts@4.3.0'
```

where i get this error:

```
data = _load_config(project_path).get("project_structure", {})
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'
```

any ideas what could it be?
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2):

I used this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/68883205/16759802
but actually changing the minus didn't help, so I just replaced the file title
**from** brownie-config.yaml **to** brownieconfig.yaml
and it compiled successfully

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that I did not format content in my YAML file correctly. I had it as `dotenv:.env` but it was supposed to be `dotenv: .env` (with a space)